# Token-based authentication for web app: how to cache token?

Tags: session, authentication, cookies, access-token, web-storage

I'm trying to switch a web app from the "traditional" cookie-based authentication mechanism to a purely token-based one. The token should be cached once received by the client to reduce overhead. What is the best way to store the token?

This is what I already learned from googling:

The first promising avenue I looked into was browser session storage, however, as far as I can tell, this isn't shared even across tabs, which means if users follow a link from the site using a new tab, they will have to log in again.

There's also local storage, but I want users to automatically be logged out when they close their browser, and I'm also a little uneasy about tokens sitting around in the storage, even though I expire them server-side. It just seems unclean.

Another way is to store the token in a session cookie, which would mean it both gets killed on browser close and can be shared across tabs. It's almost ideal, except the cookie will of course get sent over the wire with every trip to the server, which I would like to avoid if possible. Even though it's not a security issue, it seems redundant to be sending it via the cookie as well as in the HTTP Authorization header. I've thought about setting the cookie path to a non-existent path on my domain, but that's not exactly an epitome of beauty either...

So, being faced with three non-optimal solutions, I once again turn to SO for help. How do you guys do it? What's the best way?

**tl;dr What is the canonical way of persisting authentication tokens in single-page web applications?**

Comment: I'm in your same situation, have you found a solution? I think that the only solution is to use cookies with secure flag enabled to prevent some tipe of attack. I'm agree with you that it isn't a great solution but for now is the only that i have fount.

Comment: Yes, this is also the way I went, as it most closely resembles the experience users know from session based authentication mechanisms. Setting the secure flag is a good idea to prevent accidentally transmitting tokens in the clear. Be sure to use HTTPS , too.

Answer (score 0):

t;dr I'm using `localStorage` to store token.

I'm using `localStorage` for storing token on client side. You can see details of my implementation in my article: [React Token Based Authentication to Django REST API Backend](https://saasitive.com/tutorial/react-token-based-authentication-django/).

The `localStorage` shares the token across tabs and doesn't disappear when you close the tab. The data in `localStorage` persist until explicitly deleted. The data in `sessionStorage` is deleted when the session ends.

There is some discussion on the internet that `localStorage` is insecure because, in the case of the [XSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) attack, a hacker can read all data from it. Which is true. There is some discussion that httpOnly cookies are better to store the token because hackers cant access and read the token from the httpOnly cookie. It is true, but the misunderstanding is that cookies don't prevent XSS (the XSS can occur even if you use httpOnly cookies). What is more, cookies enable [CSRF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) attack. And, in the case of XSS, a hacker can still use set httpOnly cookies for malicious requests (similar to CSRF). So there is no clear winner here. The most secure way is to not store tokens on the client side.